# how to get twice path in devise routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, routes

i want to make twice url for login devise, first i want the url become to

```
"/user/sign_in"
```

and other become to

```
"/admin/sign_in"
```

how do this in devise rails?

thank you before

Answer (score 0):

```
rails generate devise User    
rails generate devise Admin
```

will create different views and routes for each MODEL

Comment: fix of my self :)
just must :

    devise_scope :user_auth do
        get "/user/sign_in", to: "user/sessions#new"
    get "/admin/sign_in", to: "admin/sessions#new"
      end